# Reset text box value when multiple clicking listview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created some code for a small application that I am working on, basically there is a list view box that when a specific row is clicked some of the details are imported into a text box below. It is working fine and the data goes in as required but if I click it again on a different row for example the information from the first click remains in the box and it will not override with the new value.

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    For i As Integer = 1 To 2
        Dim tbName As String = "TextBox" & i
        Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(tbName, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
            Dim textbox1 As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
            If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the code like this:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
For i As Integer = 1 To 2
    Dim tbName As String = "TextBox" & i
    Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(tbName, True)
    If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is TextBox Then
        Dim textbox1 As TextBox = DirectCast(matches(0), TextBox)
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Textbox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: no problem, I tried to straight away but it insisted I wait 4 mins. take care!